# C: I need a function which will accept and return a variably sized array

Tags: c, arrays, function, malloc

If this is a beginner's question, my apologies - most of my programming has been in very high level langauges, and I have limited expertise in C.  (This is the sort of thing I could do very easily in languages such as Matlab, Octave, Sage, Maxima etc, but for this I need the speed of C).

But anyway... I have an array whose size is set at run time with malloc:

```
int *A = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
```

where m is computed from some values provided by the user.  I have a function "update" which updates the array (or, if you prefer, takes the array as input and returns another as output).  This update function may be called upwards of 10^8 times.

So the function itself can't introduce the appropriately sized output array with malloc, or the memory will be used up.  So, for example, I can't do this:

```
int * update(int *L) /* produces next iteration of L */
{
  int *out = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
  /* do some stuff with L and produce new array out */
  return (out);
}
```

I've tried to make out a static variable outside the update function:

```
static int *out;
```

and define its size in main:

```
out = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
```

But this doesn't seem to work either.

Anyway, I would be very grateful of some advice - I think I've exhausted the excellence of google.

Comment: are you `free()`ing the memory after use?

Comment: _memory will be used up_: just `free()` it when no longer required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allocate the array outside of `update`, then pass a pointer to it:

```
void update(int const *L, int *out)
{
    // whatever
}
```

Call as

```
int *A = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
if (A == NULL)
    // handle error

for (i=0; i < N_ITER; i++)
     update(L, A);
```

Though you may want to redesign the program so that it updates `L` *in-place*.

Comment: Thanks very much - this is the one which seemed to work best, and which I could apply with the least amount of fiddling with my program. I tested it on some values which had caused a memory crash before, and  the update function was called approximately 200,000,000 times before I got my result.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So if you are simply wanting to work on the data that is coming into the function directly, then what you have is partially already correct.  The only thing that I would do is to add the size of the array as an input parameter to the routine to look like this:

```
void update(int * L, unsigned int size){
    unsigned int count;

    // Make sure the array has actually been allocated from outside
    if(L == NULL) return;

    // Example work on L just as if it is an array of values
    for(count = 0; count < size; count++){
        L[count] = L[count] + 1;
    }
}
```

REMEMBER, this will work if you DO NOT wish to maintain the original data within L.  If you do wish to maintain the original data, then larsmans answer will work better for you.

Also remember that you will have to malloc whatever variable you wish to input into L, outside and prior to your update routine, and free at some other point.

```
int * myVar = (int *)malloc(m * sizeof(int));

update(myVar, m);

// Other work to be done

free(myVar);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `realloc`.

```
int *a = realloc(a, m * sizeof(a[0]));
```

It will work just as `malloc` in the first run but then it will reallocate a different sized array. You should note that the new array might or might not have the previous values assigned in it. You should assume that it has garbage like all things given by `malloc`.

Here is a good explanation of using `realloc`.

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=589

NOTE : sizeof(a[0]) is equal to sizeof int but if you change int it will still be right

Comment: There's nothing in the OP's question that suggests the array size changes in between updates (and in typical iterative number crunching algorithms, such changes are rare). Also, `realloc` does copy/leave in place the previous values in the array.

Comment: I've used realloc when I've needed to adjust an array's size, but that isn't needed here.  Oh for python, where if L is a list, then 
L += [val] 
just appends the new value to it.